# 5v Battery - smaller is better

Tags: power, batteries

Does anyone know if a 5v battery exists? I'm looking for a small battery - N size is perfect - that puts out between 5v and 5.5v. A coin cell 2032 or similar would be fine too.

I can use a 9v N and regulate it, but that seems such a waste.

The application is a remote control.

Answer (score 13):

Use a single Li-ion cell with a boost converter to 5V. Microchip makes the MCP1640 boost converter chip, and other manufacturers make similar devices. [Here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01311a.pdf) is an app note describing the technique. One of the examples delivers 5V at 200 mA. The circuit could be made very small, to go with a coin cell. It has a big advantage over two cells and an LDO - it will start with a voltage as low as 0.65V, and still work with the cell discharged to 0.35V, giving a very long cell life.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on technology cell voltage is either 1.2V (NiCd), 1.5V (Alkaline, NīMH), 2V (Lead), or 3V (Lithium). You can get higher voltages by combining multiple cells. AFAIK there are no 5V batteries.

Regulating down from 9V doesn't have to be a waste, if you use a switching regulator (SMPS). For this in/out ratio efficiencies over 90% are attainable.
Alternatively you can regulate down from 2x CR2032 (in [space-saving stacking holder](http://parts.digikey.com/1/parts/1808465-holder-batt-stack-2-cr2032-smd-bhx2-2032-sm.html)) using an LDO.

**edit**
I read in your comment to another answer that the application is a remote control. In that case I'd go for the 2x CR2032 + LDO. Firstly, Lithium cells have a low self-discharge. I take it that the device is in low-power mode when not in use. You'll want an LDO with a < 1uA ground current, like Seiko [S-812C50](http://www.glyn.de/data/glyn/media/doc/S812C_E.pdf). The S-812C is available in SOT-23.
In a typical remote control application your batteries should last several years with this setup.
A switcher will typically have a higher ground current, often >10\$\mu\$A, which may considerably reduce battery life in a remote control application, where the ground current will be responsible for most of the energy use.

Comment: I might have to go the regulator route. I'd rather not use the space it takes up, but there may be no other choice. Space is really tight.

Comment: @Dirk - if you're going for small space, and running from N or coin cells, then if you have to use an active circuit to change voltage, use the switching regulator as stevenvh suggests. With tiny cells like you're talking about, a linear regulator (e.g., 7805) will waste too much energy.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're targeting 5 to 5.5V - what kind of application do you have in mind? Depending on what it is you might be able to step outside this range. Four NiCd cells will get you to 4.8V, or a pair of 2032 cells will get you 6V.

Comment: Good thinking, but the problem is space. The 5v is not especially tight. I have space for 1 N size, or 1 AAAA.

Comment: BTW, the application is a remote control.

Comment: @Dirk, most remote controls use 3V micros, which solves the problem the other way.

Comment: @Dirk, that is a good thing to include in a question.